# How to identify and select the first name from a string containing a first name and a last name?

Tags: machine-learning, entity, dictionary, interpreter

Is it possible to identify and select the first name in a string that is made up of a first name and a last name, e.g.:

```
names = {"John Smith", "Brown Dave", "Brian Miller"}
```

There are no guarantees about the order of the first name and the last name in the input string.

The result should be:

```
res = {"John Smith" -> "John", "Brown Dave" -> "Dave", "Brian Miller" -> "Brian"}
```

Does Mathematica provide any built-in function(s) for doing this, or has anyone devised a solution to tackle this problem?

---

Other commonly used terms:

First name ~ Christian name ~ Given name ~ Forename

Last name ~ Family name ~ Surname

Comment: Obligatory reminder [Falsehoods Programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 4):

We can use the [`GivenName` interpreter type](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/GivenName.html)

First we create a dictionary called `$rankLookup`.

```
names = {"John Smith", "Brown Dave", "Brian Miller"};
uniqueNames = DeleteDuplicates@Flatten@StringSplit@names;
rankUniqueNames = EntityValue[Interpreter["GivenName"][uniqueNames], "Rank"];

$rankLookup = AssociationThread[uniqueNames, rankUniqueNames]
```

> <|"John" -> 81, "Smith" -> 40149, "Brown" -> 32208, "Dave" -> 6540,
> "Brian" -> 864, "Miller" -> 4005|>

We assume that the first name is the most common one, ie has the smallest rank. So we use `Min` in the function below. This assumption deals with ambiguous names like `James Joyce`.

```
guessFirstNameBasedOnRank[name_String] :=
 Module[
  {
   firstString = StringExtract[name, 1],
   secondString = StringExtract[name, 2],
   firstStringRank,
   secondStringRank,
   firstNameDicitonary = $rankLookup,
   firstName
   },
  firstStringRank = firstNameDicitonary[firstString];
  secondStringRank = firstNameDicitonary[secondString];
  firstName = 
   First@Pick[{firstString, secondString}, {firstStringRank, 
      secondStringRank}, Min[firstStringRank, secondStringRank]];
  name -> firstName
  ];
```

Checking `Brown Dave`

```
guessFirstNameBasedOnRank["Brown Dave"]
```

> "Brown Dave" -> "Dave"

```
guessFirstNameBasedOnRank /@ names
```

> {"John Smith" -> "John", "Brown Dave" -> "Dave",   "Brian Miller" ->
> "Brian"}

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this using `TextCases`:

```
Thread[
    names -> Flatten[
            TextCases[
                Map[StringJoin @* (Riffle[#, " "] &),
                    Apply[Join, Map[Permutations @* (TextWords[#] &), names]]
                ],
                "GivenName"
            ]
        ]
  ]

(*{"John Smith" -> "John", "Brown Dave" -> "Dave", "Brian Miller" -> "Brian"}*)
```

**Edit**: As @IntroductionToProbability suggested:

```
Thread[
    names -> Flatten[
        TextCases[
                Map[StringRiffle,
                    Apply[Join, Map[Permutations @* (TextWords[#] &), names]]
                ],
                "GivenName"
            ]
    ]
 ](*Thanks, @IntroductionToProbability!*)

(*{"John Smith" -> "John", "Brown Dave" -> "Dave", "Brian Miller" -> "Brian"}*)
```

Comment: I looked at `TextCases` but couldn't get it to work naively on "Brown Dave". It looks like `Permutations` was the trick I had missed! There is also `StringRiffle` instead of `StringJoin@*(Riffle[#, " "] &)`